# regular expression match numbers in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to compare Postal Codes encoded by 4 numbers which are factor labels in R. The problem is that in 1 format the fourth digit of these codes always is 0 and in another it can vary, so I have 1010 but also 1012, 1015, but they all mean the same. Therefore, I want to read the full postal codes and replace them by the 'standard code' with 0 as fourth digit.

```
v1 <- c(,"1011", "1015", "1017","1207","1209")
v2 <- c("1010","1200")
```

How can I read all factor levels as in the vector `v1` above and systematically replace the last digit to look like vector `v2` using regular expressions?

Comment: You can try : `unique(paste0(substring(v1,1,3),"0"))`

Comment: If you're only referencing by the first three digits, why not just lose the fourth digit? E.g., `v2 <- as.factor(substr(v1, 1, 3))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the first three elements of a vector using:

```
    Three.str <- substr(v1, 1,3)
```

So, you can change all the factors starting with `"101"` using:

```
    v1[Three.str=="101"] <- "1010"
```

and so on with the corresponding codification you want to use.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now added  Three.str <- substr(vec1, 1,3) to get the first 3 numbers and plzlab<- unique(paste0(Three.str,"0"))!

Comment: Yes, I have modified the answer, because initailly I did it for the first two strings. That is why I called it `Two.str`